# Building a trie for a set of strings

Tags: c++11, stl, trie

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

struct trienode
{
    map<char, struct trienode*> m;
    bool endofword;
};

struct trienode* create_node()
{
    struct trienode* new_node = (struct trienode*)malloc(sizeof(struct trienode));
    new_node->endofword = false;
    return new_node;
};

void word_insert(struct trienode* root, string word)
{
    struct trienode* curr = root;
    for (unsigned int i =0; i < word.size(); i++) {
        if (curr->m.find(word[i]) == curr->m.end()) {
            struct trienode* new_node = create_node();
            ***curr->m.insert(pair<char, struct trienode*>(word[i], new_node) );***

        }
        curr = curr->m.find(word[i])->second;
    }
    curr->endofword = true;
}

int main()
{
    struct trienode* root = NULL;
    root = create_node();

    vector<string> v = {"aspirin", "aspetol", "astray", "atran", "chronic"};
    for (unsigned int i =0; i < v.size(); i++) {
        word_insert(root, v[i]);
    }
}
```

I am trying to build a trie data structure to hold a set of strings. I have written a word_insert() function to insert a word into the trie. For inserting a word into the trie, I start at the root node, see if the map in the root node contains the char and if yes, I proceed to the next charachter. If the char is not present in the map of the node, I create another trienode and insert an entry into the map. However, when I am doing this, I see a problem with my code. My code hangs at the point where I try to insert the (char, struct trienode*) pair into the map.

Could someone tell me what is wrong with that? Thank you.

Comment: [tag:c++] and `malloc` is not good idea.

Comment: Your program exhibits undefined behavior, by way of accessing an object whose lifetime has not yet started. `trienode` is a class with a non-trivial constructor - which does not run when you allocate raw memory for it with `malloc`. Make it `trienode* new_node = new trienode;`